# Exception Handling not handling Error in SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exception

We are handling `Exceptions` in our `stored procedures` using `Try/Catch block`. In a `stored procedure` I have intentionally made an `error` to check how the `exceptions` being handled. I wrote a `stored procedure` like as below,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        
              ;WITH CTE
              AS
              (SELECT TOP 10 * 
               FROM student)

               SELECT * FROM CTE

               SELECT * INTO #VAL
               FROM CTE

   
      IF @@ERROR = 0
              BEGIN
                  COMMIT TRAN;
              END
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
              SELECT @@ERROR AS ERROR, ERROR_LINE() AS [Error Line], ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [Error Message] 
      ROLLBACK TRAN;
      END CATCH
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

In the Above `Stored procedure` I have used a `CTE` multiple Times. I expected that `SQL-SERVER` will handle the exception but it didn't. While Executing the Above `stored Procedure` I got below `error`

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TEST, Line 16
>
> Invalid object name 'CTE'.
>
> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure TEST, Line 16
>
> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
> BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2.

Why the Exception is not handled ? Could someone give idea on this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stored procedures follow  deferred object name resolution while executing.So in this case cte is a non existent object to it .

Further try catch cannot handle this  type of errors

The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:

```
Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from running.


Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as **object name resolution errors** that occur after compilation because of deferred name resolution
```

Please see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) for more info(see errors unaffected by try catch )

Comment: Thanks for teaching me and the msdn link was really helpful :)